# 'this' pointer is undefind probably because it is missing, but how?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am getting this message:

> TypeError: this.getRandomQuestion is not a function. (In
>   'this.getRandomQuestion()', 'this.getRandomQuestion' is undefined).

I am almost sure this is because the "this" pointer isn't making it all the way to my callback (getNext() see comment). It was working earlier, but I needed to add another layer of indirection to mix the answers on my quiz up. That's when this started failing.

It seems to have the binding set up as well.

```
'use strict';
import Colors from './Colors';
import type {Node} from 'react';
import {Text, Button,View,StyleSheet, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import * as data from './data/questions.json';

export default class Question extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {thisQuestion: this.getRandomQuestion()};

        this.getRandomQuestion = this.getRandomQuestion.bind(this);
        this.getNext = this.getNext.bind(this);     
    }

    noOp() {
        return;
    }

    getRandomQuestion() {
        var questionCount = data.Questions.length;
        var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * questionCount));
        var newQ = data.Questions[randomIndex];

        var offset = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4));

        if (offset == 0) {
            newQ.a1 = newQ.Answer1;
            newQ.a2 = newQ.Answer2;
            newQ.a3 = newQ.Answer3;
            newQ.a4 = newQ.Answer4;
            newQ.click1 = this.getNext;
            newQ.click2 = this.noOp;
            newQ.click3 = this.noOp;
            newQ.click4 = this.noOp;            
        }

        if (offset == 1) {
            newQ.a4 = newQ.Answer1;
            newQ.a1 = newQ.Answer2;
            newQ.a2 = newQ.Answer3;
            newQ.a3 = newQ.Answer4;

            newQ.click4 = this.getNext;
            newQ.click1 = this.noOp;
            newQ.click2 = this.noOp;
            newQ.click3 = this.noOp;            
        }

        if (offset == 2) {
            newQ.a3 = newQ.Answer1;
            newQ.a4 = newQ.Answer2;
            newQ.a1 = newQ.Answer3;
            newQ.a2 = newQ.Answer4;
            newQ.click3 = this.getNext;
            newQ.click4 = this.noOp;
            newQ.click1 = this.noOp;
            newQ.click2 = this.noOp;            
        }

        if (offset == 3) {
            newQ.a2 = newQ.Answer1;
            newQ.a3 = newQ.Answer2;
            newQ.a4 = newQ.Answer3;
            newQ.a1 = newQ.Answer4;
            newQ.click2 = this.getNext;
            newQ.click3 = this.noOp;
            newQ.click4 = this.noOp;
            newQ.click1 = this.noOp;            
        }

        return newQ;
    }

    getNext() {
        alert('in getNext ' + this.getRandomQuestion);  // <--- this shows "in getNext undefined"
        var newQ = this.getRandomQuestion();    // this is where it fails ... not defined. Huh?
        this.setState( {thisQuestion:newQ} );       
    }

    render() {
        var thisQuestion = this.state.thisQuestion;

        return <View style={styles.body}>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>{thisQuestion.Text}</Text>
                <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                    <Button title={thisQuestion.a1} color="gray" onPress={() => thisQuestion.click1() }/>   
                </View>
                <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                    <Button title={thisQuestion.a2} color="gray" onPress={() => thisQuestion.click2() }/>  
                </View>
                <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                    <Button title={thisQuestion.a3} color="gray" onPress={() => thisQuestion.click3() }/>  
                </View>
                <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                    <Button title={thisQuestion.a4} color="gray" onPress={() => thisQuestion.click4() }/>  
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>;
    }
}
```

How do I get the "this" pointer to my callback?

**EDIT**: Added lines containing info about data (it's coming from a json file).

Comment: what is `data` inside `getRandomQuestion`? where is declared?

Comment: There is SO much that I don't know about this code. like... what language it is... what app it belongs to, the line number that was probably given with the error message...

That said, line 6 looks suspect

```
this.getRandomQuestion = this.getRandomQuestion.bind(this);
```
this.getRandomQuestion is a function. It doesn't make sense to try to assign a value to a function ( unless your language has built in capability for that ).

Comment: @Hakachukai the language and also the framework is tagged in the question, Javascript with react-native

Comment: Nico: Added the lines about where the data part comes from. It's from a json file.

Comment: are you sure its failing in the getnext method? im asking because you have a call to getrandomquestion in your constructor.

Comment: @CalvinNunes: Please post your comment about binding as an answer so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the function to a binded version of the same function in the `constructor`, I think you could just add the listener with the bind, direct to the element, for example:

```
newQ.click1 = this.getNext.bind(this)
```

And do the same for other listeners that you may have.

I, at least, prefer doing this way, furthermore, if for some reason you need to add a different bind scope to a listener (not use `this`, for example), you can, by adjusting the bind only for the specific element/listener.